# Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 automatically signing out of logged in websites

Tags: login, microsoft-edge

Just as the title is, when I am logged in to sites like Google or Microsoft, it will work for a few minutes before automatically being signed out of the site. I have tried clearing the cookies and data, resetting the settings, turning sync off and back on again, and even resetting and reinstalling the browser, but the problem persists.

Comment: Do other browsers, e.g., Firefox or Chrome, behave the same? If so, the issue might be with the accounts, rather than Edge. Also, 1. Is any add-on clearing cookies automatically? Shut all add-ons.2. Have you set OAuth2 correctly for each account?

Comment: What's your Edge version? Is your Windows up-to-date?

Comment: No, only Edge has this behaviour. Both the browser and the OS are up-to-date,

Comment: Please edit the post whenever adding new details. How did you reset the settings? Through interface? Try deleting files

Comment: Does the same happen if you open Edge in safe mode?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by renaming the `User Data` directory in:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data
```

- This ensures a new profile will be created, and once signed back into Sync, all the previous history will remain *(Microsoft really should have an option to backup the profile from within the browser and ask if you want to delete the profile when uninstalling it)*

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it was solved only by removing the microsoft authenticator from the account. So if you have it there, remove it and leave only the phone number and email for verification and the problem should disappear